# How to communicate between two child Fragments inside a Nested Fragment

Tags: android, interface, fragment

I can easily communicate between two `fragment`s of an activity by callback `interface`. Following that way, I have implemented an interface in `ParentFragment` to communicate.

But in case of activity, I was using -

```
 @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }
    }
```

And in current case, I am using `mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) getParentFragment();` instead of `mCallback = (OnHeadlineSelectedListener) activity;`. Everything is working well. Is this approach okay? Or should I do it into another thread instead `onAttach()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cast thing is to ensure certain object is instance of class that implements given interface (in this case `OnHeadlineSelectedListener`). It's irrelevant at this point what type of object it is be it activity, fragment or anything else. As long as it implements the interface you need, it is all fine.